# How to browse inside a Codeplex Archive

Tags: json, archive, codeplex

Codeplex has closed and every project archived in a handy .zip file and a lot of these are migrated on Github.
I'd like to know if is there any tool to simple browse all files in .json format inside a .zip codeplex archive.
It is difficultous to find specific release, discussion, issue or a wiki page inside the archives if the only one way is to manual browse inside each folder!

Thanks!

Comment: Furthermore, it would be wonderful if someone had a script to rename all "release" files according to releaseList.json.  :)